# Remove the url/@ etc in python

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

I am new to the python and programming in general. I have a text file contains some url/@/# etc which I want to remove to get the clean text data to feed into a machine learning algorithm.
for example the text data as follow,

```
@Su2ieQ13 But you're IMing with meeeeee. 
"@apogeum whoooaa, thats soo awesome  my eyes look like black.. except if you have a yellow light bulb close to my eyes then u can"
The shop of the day  http://
"i couldn't sleep so i stayed awake watching @lilbsuremusic on this live stream thingy and now i'm taking my butt to bed, so sweet dreams "
@Lee_Knight ok haha thanks i will try that lol
```

I have written my code as follow,

```
import re
import string

# load text negative
filename_neg = '/path/to/my/text_file'
file = open(filename_neg, encoding="ISO-8859-1")
text_neg = file.read()
text_neg = re.sub(r'^https?:\/\/.*[\r\n]*', '', text_neg,flags=re.MULTILINE)
file.close()
# split into words by white space
words_neg = text_neg.split()
print(words_neg)
```

But still I cannot remove the url etc. I would appreciate if someone could help me to solve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text_neg = re.sub('@|http://|"', '', text_neg,flags=re.MULTILINE)`.

The symbols you want to remove should be seperated by `|`.

Comment: @Urchine Thank you. Does it mean if I want to remove several symbols at once, I must write as follow? suppose if I want to remove, *, ( etc.... ext_neg = re.sub('@|http://|"|*|(|', '', text_neg,flags=re.MULTILINE)

Answer (score 1):

For your problem you can try something like this:

```
text_neg= re.sub('(http://|https://)\S*','',text_neg)
text_neg= re.sub('@\S*','',text_neg)
text_neg= re.sub('#\S*','',text_neg)
```

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: yes this work!! But is there any way to combine all three at once? Much appreciated.

Comment: You can put all three regex in one line separated by | (pipe) symbol that should do the work!